# How to connect R to a running H20 cluster on hadoop

Tags: r, hadoop

I am running h20 on a 10 node cluster on hadoop ( h20 started using h20driver.jar)

Using below command in R to connect to the cluster
`h20.init(ip="ip-address",startH20=FALSE)` fails with below error

> Cannot connect to H20 server. Please check that h20 running at
>   https://ip-address:54321

Any suggestion?

Comment: try `telnet ip-address 54321`, are you able to connect?

Comment: Yes the cluster is live and accessible. I can do telnet at the port. I can access the h20 cluster from the browser and it is active.

Answer (score 0):

Found it to be a proxy issue. Checked and removed proxy environment variable within R. 
Check if there is a proxy, i had one set 
Sys.getenv("http_proxy)
Sys.getenv("https_proxy)

Unset the proxy
Sys.setenv("http_proxy"="")
Sys.setenv("https_proxy"="")